# Schedule local notifications in the view did load method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications, ios9

i'm a noob to programming on swift, and i'm facing a problem. I'm trying to schedule a local notification every day at the same hour, this without the user scheduling it. Some how the repeat interval method gives me more that one notification at the time. So i don't now what's happening. Basically what i want is to schedule the notification properly and call the schedule method in the right way.

This is my view controller method where i call the notification

```
      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      notificar.scheduleNotification("message")     
}
```

This is the notification helper class

```
class NotificationHelper {

static func askPermission() {

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}



 func scheduleNotification(InputUser:String) {

    let now: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: NSDate())

    let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let date = cal.dateBySettingHour(now.hour, minute: now.minute + 1, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())
    let reminder = UILocalNotification()
    reminder.fireDate = date
    reminder.alertBody = InputUser
    reminder.alertAction = "Cool"
    reminder.soundName = "sound.aif"
    reminder.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute




    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminder)

    print("Firing at \(now.hour):\(now.minute+1)")
}
```

And this is my app delegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    NotificationHelper.askPermission()

    return true
}
```

As you can see, in the code im calling every minute the notification repeat interval, but as soon as the notification gets called i recive an stack of 5 notifications in a row, not  single one.

please any ideas, i will be very grateful. And sorry for my english. 
thanks :)

Comment: According to your code a **new** notification is created every time your view controller is loaded. You will have to set a flag the first time the notification is scheduled (and persist it) so that the notification is set once or cancel all notifications before scheduling a new one. Also, your repeat interval is `NSCalendarUnit.Minute` instead of `NSCalendarUnit.Day`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove local notification first and then add a new one here is the code.

```
var app: UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
var eventArray: [AnyObject] = app.scheduledLocalNotifications()
for oneEvent: UILocalNotification in eventArray 
{
    var userInfoCurrent: [NSObject : AnyObject] = oneEvent.userInfo
    var uid: String = "\(userInfoCurrent["name"])"
// here give the name of your local notification.
    if (uid == obj["name"]) 
    {
        //Cancelling local notification
        app.cancelLocalNotification(oneEvent)
    }
}
```